# How to indicate in Chinese text that a quote has been translated from English?

Tags: translation

In a Chinese text, if I used a quote that was in English, but was translated into Chinese, how would I indicate this?

For example, if Tom said "I have a house", and to quote Tom in the text, I wrote:

汤姆说：“我有一套房子”。

Where and how would I indicate that “我有一套房子” is a translation from English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once an English sentence is translated into Chinese, you can treat it as Chinese.

(上引号 - upper quotation mark) = 「

(下引号 - lower quotation mark) = 」

Tom said "I have a house" = 汤姆说：「我有一套房子」。

It is very common for people to use English quotation mark in Chinese text, there is nothing wrong with 汤姆说：“我有一套房子”.

> *In a Chinese text, if I used a quote that was in English, but was translated into Chinese, how would I indicate this?*

I would write:

汤姆说：「我有一套房子 (I have a house) 」。

汤姆说："我有一套房子 (I have a house)".

If you don't want to use English in the sentence at all, you can write:

汤姆说：「我有一套房子 (英文) 」。

汤姆说："我有一套房子 (英文)".